# Structured If / Else Statements In MYSQL's Equivalent CASE Statements

Tags: mysql, case

I'm trying to create the same type of logic that I've demonstrated below using simple if/else statements in MYSQL using CASE statements.

Basically, if the first condition is correct then I was to abandon the rest. If the first doesn't but the second does then abandon the rest etc.

So in this context I will be filling the first blank column in the database from left to right meaning "nwc_signup" as shown below.

```
if(rota.nwc_signup_1 = '') {

    rota.nwc_signup_1 = ?

} else {

    if(rota.nwc_signup_2 = '') {

        rota.nwc_signup_2 = ?

    } else {

         if(rota.nwc_signup_3 = '') {

            rota.nwc_signup_3 = ?

         } else {


             if(rota.nwc_signup_4 = '') {

                rota.nwc_signup_4 = ?

             } 

         }

    }

}
```

I've tried using CASE statements in MYSQL but it flags an error. Has anyone got an ingenious idea to help which would be much appreciated.

```
        UPDATE 

            `rota` 

            INNER JOIN `signups` 
            ON 
            signups.signups_user_id = rota.signups_user_id

            INNER JOIN `pre_rota` 
            ON 
            pre_rota.signups_user_id = signups.signups_user_id

        SET

            CASE 

                WHEN rota.nwc_signup_1 = ''

                    THEN rota.nwc_signup_1 = ?

                    ELSE 

                        CASE 

                            WHEN rota.nwc_signup_2 = ''

                                THEN rota.nwc_signup_2 = ?

                                ELSE 

                        END
            END,

        WHERE 

        pre_rota.nwc_username = 'jacktrow'
```

The MYSQL Error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE 

                WHEN rota.nwc_signup_1 = ''

                    THEN SET rota.nwc_si' at line 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of SQL seems to work perfectly. The data will be inserted into the first in the total of four `nwc_signup`columns that are empty, meaning it is not be inserted in any of the other columns once it's found the empty one starting from the first column right the way to the fourth column.

```
       SET 

            rota.nwc_signup_1 = (CASE WHEN rota.nwc_signup_1 = '' 

                                      THEN ? ELSE rota.nwc_signup_1 END),

            rota.nwc_signup_2 = (CASE WHEN (rota.nwc_signup_1 != '' AND 
                                            rota.nwc_signup_2 = '') 

                                      THEN ? ELSE rota.nwc_signup_2 END),

            rota.nwc_signup_3 = (CASE WHEN (rota.nwc_signup_1 != '' AND  
                                            rota.nwc_signup_2 != '' AND 
                                            rota.nwc_signup_3 = '')

                                      THEN ? ELSE rota.nwc_signup_3 END),

            rota.nwc_signup_4 = (CASE WHEN (rota.nwc_signup_1 != '' AND  
                                            rota.nwc_signup_2 != '' AND 
                                            rota.nwc_signup_3 != '' AND 
                                            rota.nwc_signup_4 = '')

                                      THEN ? ELSE rota.nwc_signup_4 END),
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case` cannot be used on the left side of `set`, only the right.  You can use `case` for each column:

```
   SET rota.nwc_signup_1 = (CASE WHEN rota.nwc_signup_1 = '' THEN ? ELSE END),
       rota.nwc_signup_2 = (CASE WHEN rota.nwc_signup_1 = '' THEN rota.nwc_signup_2
                                 WHEN rota.nwc_signup_1 = '' THEN ?
                                 ELSE rota.nwc_signup_2
                            END)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's much appreciated, I was confused with your code and please correct me if I'm wrong but I couldn't see it working in the situation I wanted. However it did educate and inspire me to create what I've found to work where I've posted it as my answer.